# Xcode Cloud Errors Building Local SPMs that Work Locally "an out-of-date resolved file was detected"

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, swift-package, xcode-cloud

Have added 2 Swift packages locally. (GraphQL code gens for Swift using Apollo iOS SDK v1.9.0). I'm using Xcode to manage the Swift packages. They've been added to the Project > Package Dependancies as well as linked in the Targets > Build Phases > Linked Binaries With Libraries. For both our target.

Everything works correctly when building locally but when I try to build on Xcode Cloud we get these errors:

Could not resolve package dependencies:
an out-of-date resolved file was detected at /Volumes/workspace/repository/Play.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved, which is not allowed when automatic dependency resolution is disabled; please make sure to update the file to reflect the changes in dependencies. Running resolver because the following dependencies were added: 'myPackage' (/Volumes/workspace/repository/MyProject/MyPackage)
fatalError

an out-of-date resolved file was detected at /Volumes/workspace/repository/MyProject.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved, which is not allowed when automatic dependency resolution is disabled; please make sure to update the file to reflect the changes in dependencies. Running resolver because the following dependencies were added: 'myPackage' (/Volumes/workspace/repository/MyProject/MyPackage)fatalError2024-02-28 12:07:52.786 xcodebuild[4161:18697] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/pc/xhyhfmrd1mq975kcng4w278r0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2024-28-02_12-07-0052.xcresult

I've removed the Package.resolved from git ignore, but it still happens. I've tried every option to "resolve package versions" and update the package versions.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!